# Excel: Populate Sheet name for given Variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have one Workbook with multiple projects. Each project has it's own sheet with the project name. In column A I have a list of order numbers (Ordernub).

In another sheet called "MasterList" contains all of the order numbers across all project. This list is also in column A and there is no header.

I need a function or Macro that will: search all of my sheets (bar MasterList) and will populate the sheet name the order can be found in column B.

I tried INDIRECT but had little luck.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to fill in some blanks but something like:

```
For each rgOrder in rgMasterList
     for each wsSheet in thisworkbook.sheets
            if wsSheet.codename <> wsMasterList.codename then
                set rgMatch = wsSheet.columns(1).find rgOrder.value
                if not rgMatch is nothing then
                    rgOrder.offset(0,1).value = wsSheet.name
                    exit for
                end if
            end if
     next ' the "exit for" above exits this inner For
 next
```

Or if it can be in multiple worksheets replace with

```
if not rgMatch is nothing then
    rgOrder.offset(0,1).value = rgOrder.offset(0,1).value & ", " & wsSheet.name
end if
```

Comment: or i guess you could just do a workbook.find and check the results not on the masterlist sheet hmm... would be more efficient :P Cant recall how to do .Find over the whole workbook though *shrug*

Comment: Simon, I am a novice here.

In the first line I added Sub Find(). Then when I hit run I get a syntax error at set rgMatch = wsSheet.columns(1).find rgOrder.value  Can you help me here?

Comment: they're the blanks I was talking about :) that one might actually just be a bracket issue... try wsSheet.columns(1).find(rgOrder.value) instead... plus read the built in Excel help on the .find function: I don't say that to be belligerent, it's actually a really good article/documentation